# How to have the Sublime Text console showing color instead of the color codes

Tags: sublimetext2

I have a build system output in the console. However it is showing color code instead of the actual colorized text.

```
[37;46;1mTest file: static/tests/casperjs/login/test.js
```

How can I apply a color theme to the console output?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure the console is able to be colorized...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately sublime doesn't support this.  I ended up writing a plugin that parses the output and converts it into a colored version (for a subset of colors, ones we use in our testing framework).

If you would like to look into that, or if anyone stumbles upon this in future here are some tips..

I detect output in the plugin with an **on_modified** event listener and a view 
with no name (**view.name()**). This does not uniquely identify the output pane
so you'll have to do a bit more than that, I found no other easy way (unless
you want to hook into your build plugin and act directly on the view it generates).
To make the color changes, I remove the color codes (**view.erase()**) and add color to the 
regions marked by those codes with **view.add_regions()**.  The colors I add are
ones I manually insert into a custom theme, as again there seems to be no
other way.  Also, for some reason it seems you can't add a color with the 
exact background of the active theme (it inverts it or something), so I set
the color's backgrounds to something just different.

As you can tell, it's a hacky, ad hoc solution, otherwise I would release it on Github.

You can also check out [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL), it does console text coloring